# GeoJSON file not being rendered using Folium

Tags: python-3.x, geojson, folium, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth map using Folium. I exported a GeoJSON file for London boroughs from an official GIS shapefile. After hours of researching about possible causes, I noticed in my file that the features come up in a different order compared to another GeoJSON file that works, which I assume is the reason for not appearing on the map. Basically the order in mine is something like

```
"features": [ 
    "geometry": {...}, 
    "properties": {...}, etc
```

and the working GeoJSON has

```
"features": [ 
   "properties": {...},
   "geometry": {...},
```

My question is How can I change the order of the features or how to make it render with Folium?

The code for creating the map is as follows:

```
london = r'london_simple.json' # geojson file
# create a plain London map
london_map = folium.Map(location=[51.5074, 0.1278], zoom_start=10)

london_map.choropleth(
   geo_data = london,
   data = dfl1,
   columns = ['Area_name', 'GLA_Population_Estimate_2017'],
   key_on='feature.properties.Counties_1',
   fill_color = 'YlOrRd',
   fill_opacity = 0.7,
   line_opacity=0.2,
   legend_name='Population size in London'
   )
london_map
```

I'm working in a jupyter notebook on IBM Watson, if that makes any difference. If I use my geojson file, no choropleth regions appear. If I change to the other file, it works (provided I change the map coordinates to Toronto ([37.7749, -122.4194]).

My code doesn't generate any error, just the plain map focused on London without the choropleth regions.

[Link to working geojson](https://github.com/adrianturculet/Coursera_Capstone/blob/master/sanfran.json)

[Link to my problematic geojson](https://github.com/adrianturculet/Coursera_Capstone/blob/master/london_simple.json)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this instead?

```
key_on='feature.properties.Counties_a'
```

I think the code beginning with E should identify the relevant part of the shapefile.

Comment: I tried with 'Countie_a' as well. No luck. I don't think the issue is with the key. I have a feeling it is to do with the order or the elements in the file when comparing the two json files

Comment: 'Countie' or 'Counties'?  Big difference

Comment: Sorry I omitted the 's' by mistake. As mentioned above, the issue was with the file.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few problems with the JSON file for London-

1. The coordinate values are faulty. They contain values such as [532946.0999999996, 181894.90000000037] when in reality it should be something like [ -0.042770, 51.531530 ].
2. There seem to be very few values to draw a polygon of the counties.

Search for an alternative Geojson for London, I found a working one [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sjwhitworth/london_geojson/master/london_postcodes.json)

Comment: Thanks for checking this out. Your geojson works indeed, but it is at Postcode level. I was interested in borough level. So in case anyone else has this problem, I went and downloaded a shapefile from [data.gov](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/6cdebf5d-c69b-4480-8c9c-53ab8a816b9d/statistical-gis-boundary-files-for-london) and then converted the shapefile into GeoJSON format for rendering in Folium using [mapshaper.org](https://mapshaper.org/). The map needs to be simplified before exporting to geojson, otherwise it will not work in Folium.